# Once a muslim, always a muslim?

Tags: allah

I'm new to stackexchange and got this question for you.

When I was younger - 19 y.o., aproximately - I went to a mosque for a few months, made friends with some muslims including our Imam and I reverted to Islam. I was catholic before.

The point is that I've never got so much support of my family and weeks later I needed to move to another city where there wasn't any mosque or muslims community.

So basically, all I did was saying the words:

> لا إله إلا الله محمد رسول الله

And that was all.

I did not have enough time to learn arabic, to learn more about their culture, to learn how to pray, to get attached to their rules and I also did not followed any of the mandatory rules of islam.
I mean, I eat pork, I hang out with woman, and so forth.

So... Now, I'm about to graduate in college, I feel kind of old and also I feel like I need some guidance, some spiritual strength and I don't even know what to believe, to be honest.
I know that I believe in God. But... What else?

What do you guys think? What should I do?

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE the Q&A site about Islam. To make yourself familiar with our site and model I recommend you to take the [tour] and check our [help]. Note that questions like "What should I...?" and "What do you think...?" attract opinion-based answers which make them off topic (see [ask]). So please consider editing your post to make it reasonably answerable.

Comment: Once you've spoken out the two shahada اشهد ان لا اله الا الله وان محمد رسول الله you are considered a Muslim, now you should ask yourself do you want to be a good Muslim or continue as before. If you made the first choice you should first repent and refrain from any bad deeds you've done and start to gain knowledge about Islam and begin practicing Islam (prayer fast etc.) for this you need guidance you may get it by seeking help in a Muslim community, asking questions reading books. Remember that there's always a second opinion so seek your own truth by good and sincere investigation.

Answer (score 1):

Whoever utters the words لا إله إلا الله محمد رسول الله while knowing its meaning and believing in it sincerely is a Muslim without any doubt.

Next, eating pork and hanging out with women is a sin, and sins do not nullify ones' Islam unless such a person declares these sins to be lawful.

The Prophet (saw) said:

> التائب من الذنب كمن لا ذنب له "The one who repents from a sin is like
>   the who does not have a sin" (Ibn Maajah, al-Bayhaqi in al-Shu'ab, and
>   al-Tabarani in al-Kabeer).

Allah said:

> When those come to thee who believe in Our signs, Say: "Peace be on
>   you: Your Lord hath inscribed for Himself (the rule of) mercy: verily,
>   if any of you did evil in ignorance, and thereafter repented, and
>   amend (his conduct), lo! He is Oft-forgiving, Most Merciful. (Quran,
>   6:54)

Allah said:

> But whoever repents after his crime, and amends his conduct,
>   Allah turneth to him in forgiveness; for Allah is Oft-forgiving, Most
>   Merciful. (Quran, 5:39).

It is clear from that all this that the best option for you now is to repent to Allah and be steadfast in learning the basics of worshipping Allah.

Comment: Without the testimony اشهد that is not sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

It is a very good sign that you feel bad for sinning, you should try as much as possible to stop those sins is my advice!

Now, to your questions, to be a Muslim you **must** first have a belief that God exists and that Mohammad(PBUH) is his prophet "لا إله إلا الله محمد رسول الله" are words that mean your approval of this. but, is it enough? Definitely not, you must do what God asks you to and abandon what he ordered you to not do, you must pray, pay zakat, fast in Ramadan, and do Hij whenever possible(after learning it of course[which means you should try to learn it as soon as possible]) and also you have to stop doing any of the bad stuff you are doing, as much as you can.

learning Arabic isn't mandatory at all(it just makes it easier for you, it isn't a must), what you should do in your position is spend some time searching what to do as a new Muslim and how to do things right for example [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r5usX8JYxgg)  is a video teaching how to pray. you can search about fundamental stuff on Islam, you could start asking committed Muslims about this stuff, going to mosques and asking the Imam would be very helpful.

As to "spiritual strength", learning Arabic might help, you could start then to read Quran and try to understand it. Even without learning arabic, just play Quran on your mobile phone or pc as much as possible(always if possible) and listen to it("Nasser AlQtami" is a very good citer of Quran and "Ayat" is a great program for playing Quran), that might help, also go to mosques a lot and ask about your religion.

**May God bless you and lead you to him**

Answer (score 0):

No! Once a Muslim is not always a muslim. Because after being Muslim for some reason at a point in life if a person does believe that there is no God and His prophets, books are all lie then I believe that person is not a Muslim anymore.

In your case it is good that you are still believe in God and there are lot of chance to ask forgiveness for your wrong doings.

So my suggestions are following,

- learn and follow the basics of islam (e.g. five pillars of Islam)
- learn to pray (salat) and ask forgiveness
- try to avoid the works those are considered sin in Islam
- gradually study Qur’an (in your own language) and implement the teachings from it in your life.